# RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2 error with Websocket server

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, websocket

I want to send a message from my SSL Website to my php-websocket server. The server uses a wildcard certificate.

This is the client:

```
var wsUri = "wss://ticket.qwellcode.de:9001";
websocket_qcode_intern = new WebSocket(wsUri);
```

And this my Websocket server:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);    
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);    
socket_listen($socket);
...
```

To decrypt a message (e.g the header) I use the following code:

```
function decryptString($cryptText)
{
    $keyFile=fopen("PATH/TO/pemfile.pem","r") or die("NOT FOUND");
    $privateKey=fread($keyFile,8192);
    fclose($keyFile);

    openssl_get_privatekey($privateKey);
    $binText = base64_decode($cryptText);

    /* NOT WORK WITH THIS PADDING */
    //openssl_private_decrypt($binText,$clearText,$privateKey,OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
    openssl_private_decrypt($binText,$clearText,$privateKey);
    print openssl_error_string();
    return($clearText);
}
```

The problem is that with the padding "OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING" (or other paddings) I get the following message:

```
error:0407106B:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block
type is not 02
```

With the option "OPENSSL_NO_PADDING" I get crap decoded code like this:

```
▬♥☺ ø☺  ù♥☻→ª   ↕ FRomTý¤▬3Åµ▬g»►F↕Ñ;nÏágdCH╝  *└
└       └‼└¶└↕└└◄ 3 2 E 9 8 ê ▬ / A 5 ä
 ♣ ♦☺  D   ↑ ▬  ‼domain.de ☺ ☺
 ♠ ↨ ↑ ↓ ♂ ☻☺  #  3t   ♣ ♣☺
```

I Use a SSL-Zetificat with the encryption, PKCS #1 SHA-1 - AES 128 CBC with SHA 1.

How can I decrypt this code ? ... I tryed everything .. And yes I know, I can use stream socket.. but I will solve this for me with the "normal" php-socket ...

Why am I having trouble decrypting? Is there a solution?

Comment: *"RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2 error ..."* - you often see this with (1) text encoding errors - you're not decrypting binary data; rather your are trying to decrypt Base64 encoded data. Or (2) you are using mismatched keys. That is, the public key is not matched to the private key. You should probably show your keys, too (assuming the private key is a test key).

Comment: Can you show the string that you're trying to decrypt?